# Random background images CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

I am doing small website, however I have like 5-6 images for my background, and I want to make it random every time I refresh the page. This is what I got in style.css :

```
html {   
    background:  url(image/l2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed
    -webkit-background-size: cover
    -moz-background-size: cover
    -o-background-size: cover
    background-size: cover   
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I ve tried the php example below, like 2 days ago and it was not working. Might be the reason that I putted it somewhere wrong

Comment: you can't use the PHP if your file extension is `.html`.. that could be the problem.

Comment: no I ve changed it of course to .php,still not

Comment: Are you running it using a WAMP / MAMP or directly on an Apache Server?

Answer (score 19):

You cant use only html & css for this purpose. You should do it client side(like with javascript) or server side(like a php script)

Here's php example:

```
<?php
  $bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{
background: url(images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
}
-->
</style>
```

Here's jquery example:

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg'];
$('html').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
```

Comment: ok where exactly I need to put it? in index.html? before DOCTYPE?

Comment: You could use jquery example and place this code at the head tag. Remember include your jquery.js file

Comment: ok , but I want also other attributes webkit-background-size: cover
    -moz-background-size: cover
    -o-background-size: cover
    background-size: cover

Comment: no problem. You put your css like you did, but also add this code

Comment: ok i putted inside <head> and it is just showing the same text on webstie

Comment: Did you include jquery? Did you change image array values to the ones you're looking?

Comment: I ve downloaded jquery and placed it on folder. Yes I changed everything similar to code

Comment: You should add <script src="jquery.js"></script> in your head before code

Comment: ok I did. now there is no background at all. Do I need to change something in style.css?

Comment: Did you change the var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg']; array? You should change the name to your images names

Comment: Can I send my files to you by email?

Comment: i think you cant do this in stackoverflow

Comment: this is a front end question - php is a back end language; no need to use that.

Answer (score 9):

I would use JS. Take a look at this example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var totalCount = 8;
function ChangeIt() 
{
var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
document.body.background = 'bgimages/'+num+'.jpg';
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";// Background repeat
}
</script>
</head>
<body> 
// Page Design 
</body> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
ChangeIt();
</script> 
</html>
```

You would need to name your images the proper numbers through the random count and place them in that images folder.

Comment: All images must be in root folder? or it can be still taken from "images" folder?

Comment: They are taken from a folder called 'bgimages'.

Comment: ok, it will work as my CSS3 attributes? Stretch to the whole window?

Answer (score 8):

For jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var bgArray = ['bg1.jpg', 'bg2.jpg', 'bg3.jpg'];
    var bg = bgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArray.length)];

    $('body').css('background', bg);

    // If you have defined a path for the images
    var path = 'images/bg/';

    // then you can put it right before the variable 'bg'
    $('body').css('background', path+bg);

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: where should I place it? will it be stretch backgrounds?

Comment: between these tags `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` inside the head tag as Matthew Camp has shown. and then you need to refer to the jQuery library: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` also inside the head tag.

Comment: check edit. Just copy the code and insert it inside the head tag. The part with comments can be deleted if there is no path to the images.

Comment: I did everything you said, still got white background. =(

Answer (score 3):

Really short option: (if you can use php in the page).  Substitute the urls of your backgrounds for the filenames that are in single quotes.

```
background: url('<?php $a = array('darkred.jpg','red.gif','pink.png'); echo $a[array_rand($a)];?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using pure CSS. You must to use javascript to random and set the background image of your website.

Comment: user2136883 didn't mention it but he/she tagged jQuery. I'm guessing that's why there's downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the last answer is very short, but how if you put them in one folder?

```
<?php
$pt = 'BGs/';  //folder where you put your BGs       
$bg = array($pt.'bg_ants.png', $pt.'bg_boobs.png', $pt.'bg_circles.png' ); // array of filenames
?>
<Body background="<?php echo $bg[array_rand($bg)]; ?>">
```

You can save it in one file and include it to use the code at your other pages.
For example: you save it as "rand.htm". Just replace the `<body>` tag with this code.

```
<?php include("rand.htm"); ?>
```

Comment: if you're going to use PHP, then you might as well use `scandir` to get the list of images in the folder, rather than hardcoding them.