# random fullscreen background image on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, css, random, fullscreen

Im using this script that I found online to have a random background image on whenever the browser is refreshed.

CSS

```
body{ 
background: no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var images=['images/001.jpg',
            'images/002.jpg',
            'images/003.jpg',
            'images/004.jpg',
            'images/005.jpg',];

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
var bgImg = 'url(' + images[randomNumber] + ')';

$('body').css({'background':bgImg, 'background-size':'cover', });

});
```

Works fine on screens larger than 1150px but anything less than that, the images starts piling up one on top of another. How can I get this to stretch out no matter what screen size. I dont care if the image gets cropped on small screens as long as it fills the lot.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/36cL6/)**

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var classCycle=['imageCycle1','imageCycle2'];

    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * classCycle.length);
    var classToAdd = classCycle[randomNumber];

    $('body').addClass(classToAdd);

});
```

Comment: this is the example I am having problems with

Answer (score 3):

I found this article 
[Random background images CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231812/random-background-images-css3)
and this solved the issue

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var totalCount = 5;
function ChangeIt() 
{
var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
document.body.background = 'images/'+num+'.jpg';
document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";// Background repeat
}
</script>
</head>
<body> 

// Page Design 
</body> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
ChangeIt();
</script> 
</html>
```

Thank you anyway :)

Comment: even with this I had problems as the "html doctype" started messing with the javascript.
feel free to comment..

Answer (score 0):

Use Falu's answer that is voted as correct, but implement CSS methods used as a #1 solution in this post - [Perfect Full Page Background Image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

```
.imageCycle1{
background:url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
 filter:    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";}
```

It works great for every screen size.