# Randoming image with javascript and apply a background color to the page according the randomed image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Title says all. I have the following JS code:

```
function randomImg(){
var myImages = new Array();
myImages[1] = "images/image1.gif";
myImages[2] = "images/image2.gif";
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages.length);
if(rnd == 0){
rnd = 1;
}
document.write('<img src="'+myImages[rnd]+'" alt="image" style="border: 0;" />');
}
```

Both images have different content, so the page background image should be different also. Here's the CSS for the page background:

```
/* image1.gif */
body {
background-color: #FBFBFB;
}

/* image2.gif */
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Also I'd like not to use jQuery because I've already added a library. So the only acceptable jQuery code should be the one compatible with: jquery-1.4.3.min.js

Comment: It's not enough for a full-on answer at this point, but if you will have many images possibly, might I suggest putting the background color into your array, like such: `var img = [{"img":"images/image1.gif","bg":"#FBFBFB"},{"img":"images/image2.gif","bg":"#FFFFFF"}];` Then when you select a random element in the array, you also get the background color right there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [random fullscreen background image on browser refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288950/random-fullscreen-background-image-on-browser-refresh)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `document.write` as this will clear your document content. To make different background based on random number you can do for example:

```
if(rnd == 0){
    rnd = 1;
    document.body.style.background = '#FBFBFB';
} else {
    document.body.style.background = '#FFFFFF';
}
```

Or using jQuery:

```
if(rnd == 0){
    rnd = 1;
    $( 'body' ).css( 'background', '#FBFBFB' );
} else {
    $( 'body' ).css( 'background', '#FFFFFF' );
}
```

Compatible with jQuery 1.4.3 too.

As you are using jQuery, you can avoid using `document.write` by

```
$( 'body' ).append( '<img src="'+myImages[rnd]+'" alt="image" style="border: 0;" />' );
```

Full edited code should be:

```
function randomImg() {
    var myImages = [];
    myImages[0] = "images/image1.gif";
    myImages[1] = "images/image2.gif";
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages.length);
    if (rnd == 0) {
        rnd = 1;
        $('body').css('background', '#FBFBFB');
    } else {
        $('body').css('background', '#FFFFFF');
    }
    $('body').append('<img src="' + myImages[rnd] + '" alt="image" style="border: 0;" />');
}
```

Comment: Using the above code (not the jQuery) will produce only `#FFFFFF` but won't random the colors for some strange reason...

Comment: @Charlie this is because you have a typo in `myImages.lenght` should be `myImages.length`

Comment: But I already fixed it. Or if you think there's something else can you edit your answer with the full edited code?

Comment: It works well for me, just `FBFBFB` is very bright color, this is why you think it's white. Try to refresh several times this jsFiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/Fks24/