# How to set background randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the Aerial template from [HTML5UP](http://html5up.net/aerial)  and am trying to get the scrolling background to be chosen randomly from a set of images. How would I accomplish this?

Currently the background is set in a block of code like this:

```
#bg {
    background: #348cb2 url("images/bg.jpg") bottom left;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }
```

I found this StackOverflow question that may be what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to implement it. [random fullscreen background image on browser refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288950/random-fullscreen-background-image-on-browser-refresh)

Comment: Here's a start: `var arr = ['bg1.jpg', 'bg2.jpg']; $('#id').css({backgroundImage:arr[(Math.random()*arr.length).toFixed(0)]});`

Comment: @RienNeVaPlu͢s By combining some of your code with the other StackOverflow answer, I got it to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var images=['https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1422405153578-4bd676b19036?q=75&fm=jpg&s=5ecc4c704ea97d85ea550f84a1499228', 'https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1423439793616-f2aa4356b37e?q=75&fm=jpg&s=3b42f9c018b2712544debf4d6a4998ff',];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
var bgImg = 'url(' + images[randomNumber] + ')';

$('#bg').css({'background':bgImg});
```