# Random image css with attribution

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to do a random image in ruby on rails in the background via css. The difference being I want to also display a attribution to the person who took the image. I'm only going to have 5 images so don't see the need for a database. I want to keep it low maintenance. What is the best way to extend the following?

```
<style type="text/css">
  html {
    background: url(<%= randomized_background_image %>) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  }
</style>
```

Now in your application_helper

```
def randomized_background_image
  images = ["assets/foo.jpg", "assets/random.jpg", "assets/super_random"]
  images[rand(images.size)]
end
```

Comment: So where are you pulling the attribution data from?

Comment: @Paulie_D I guess this is part of my question - really it just needs to be a name. Can it go in the application helper alongside the image reference? What would be best practice?

Comment: Frankly,most of what you have is beyond me. The question is, once you have the data how do you get it on the page. Where would you like it to appear? if we have the information somewhere it can be output to an html object and inserted dynamically into the page (probably with JS). To be honest however, you're probably better off just editing the images  one by one to add an'attribution watermark', Since you only have 5 this would be a small task and then you don't need to change a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first a disclaimer, I don't think you should be doing this. Embedding Ruby in CSS is pretty sloppy. Why? It crosses abstraction layers and mixes concerns unnecessarily.

Ruby (and erb templates generally) really don't have a great model of your document object, but guess who does? Jquery! :) So as an alternative, take a look at the $ examples in the answers to this question: [Random background images CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231812/random-background-images-css3)

That said, to do this in Ruby, the way to do it would be to have a hash object for each of your images then put them in your array, ie:

```
image_hash = Hash[url: 'http://', attribution: 'Author K. Dude']
=> {:url=>"http://", :attribution=>"Author K. Dude"}
image_hash[:url]
=> "http://"
array_of_image_hashes = Array[image_hash]
=> [{:url=>"http://", :attribution=>"Author K. Dude"}]
array_of_image_hashes.first[:url]
=> "http://"
```

This way you could share the same local variable (a random index of your array) in your view both at the style level and just as a string in a span underneath it. So, <%= random_image_result[:url] %> in style and <%= random_image_result[:author] %> in a span. I'm guessing you're doing Rails, and if so, I'd recommend putting your generator method in a helper, which is included automatically at the controller level so it is available to your view.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your input. I ended up using a jQuery solution.