# Randomizing CSS3 HTML5

Tags: php, html, css

I want to randomize the background image on my site, I figure I need to make an array and then randomly select one of the images in the array so that the page delivers randomized graphics every time.  But how do you do this in css3/html?

I figure I should use php or java, but then how do I configure that into a site based on css3 and html.  If the file is index.html, it won't execute php, would it?

Perhaps I can make an external php function to reference from other directories from my index.html source?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random background images CSS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231812/random-background-images-css3)

Comment: You are over thinking your question, take a deep breath and come back to it ;)

Comment: If I use any PHP, all my files have to be .php, correct?  Unless I use javascript, then I can just include a randomization script in <head>?

Comment: No you can use PHP in an html file if you update your `.htaccess` see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files

Comment: Then all the page will be run as php, not html?  Is this considered bad practice in professional sites?

Comment: Why would it be considered bad practice? You are still over thinking this.