# JQuery / JS random background image solution for ::before element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, error-handling

[COMMENT] **I forgot to mention that I loaded JQuery 1.9 before**

I read and followed a couple of possible solutions for my question, but I'm totally stuck.

Now I've got a static background-image for a block that's placed :before a div, but I'd like to show a random background (image) for that block.

This is what I have so far:
// [Random background images CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231812/random-background-images-css3)
// Answered by Dimser @ Mar 5 '13 at 18:59

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var bgArray = ['benjamin.png', 'peter.png', 'auke.png'];
var bg = bgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArray.length)];

$('body').css('background', bg);

// Defined a path for the images
var path = 'https://nieuw.koffiematters.nl/images/';

$('body').css('background', path+bg);
```

});

In this sample, I decided to test without the ::before element, but this gives me an error: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Before we can move on, this error needs to be fixed first, right? After that, I would like to hear what your approach would be to get it work on the ::before element.

I don't have full access to the source, so it's not possible for me to add / change / remove classes in the regular way. This is the JSFiddle file:

http://jsfiddle.net/3khmzsn1/21/

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to add jQuery in your example .

you haven't direct access to `::after, ::before` pseudo selectors but you can try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/b7oqx8r3/

Answer (score 0):

The jquery is not loading in your code. In jsfiddle you can select the framework in top of your javascript code. Here is the updated code

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231812/random-background-images-css3
// Answered by Dimser @ Mar 5 '13 at 18:59

$(document).ready(function() {

    var bgArray = ['benjamin.png', 'peter.png', 'auke.png'];
    var bg = bgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArray.length)];

    /* $('body').css('background', bg); */

    // Defined a path for the images
    var path = 'https://nieuw.koffiematters.nl/images/';

        // As :before / :after aren't part of the DOM, I can't use the following syntax as far as I know:
    // $('body div::before).css('background', path+bg);
    // But the sample from Dimser doesn't work either. This is the error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    $('body').css('background', path+bg);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4bf3gvkj/

Answer (score 0):

You're the best! But ... it was my fault that I didn't mention that I loaded JQuery correctly before, so that's not the issue unfortunately.

I tried Websiteproduct's idea and I really believed in it! But ... unfortunately at the point of Live-implementation, there's a bottleneck. It's a template file for Freshdesk, which uses the Liquid framework. I didn't mention it, because I wasn't expecting getting into trouble with a small peace of JS. When I reconstruct the solution of ***websiteproduct*** It looks like the brackets in the **append** location are ignored. I made a screenshot:

[image]

I don't know if I'm right, but should I break that line (don't know how exactly), so the variables would be accepted maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using expressions like `${variable}` you should use another quotes not 'single' and not "double", use `backtick` instead.

So, there is working code below:

```
$('head').append('<style>.ticket-page .c-ticket-row::before { background-image: url(' + path + bg + ') }</style>');
```