# Random background image on hover

Tags: php, css, image, hover

On my main page website, I have 6 tiles and I would like to change the background on the hover effect. I found PHP script below but something is not working properly

In my index.php file below  tag, U put below code

```
  <?php
  $bg = array('nasa1-400.jpg', 'nasa1-1200.jpg', 'nasa1-640.jpg'); // array of filenames
  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
```

and in my CSS file, I use the below code

```
 div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1):hover
{
  background: url(images/bg/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
 }
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: PHP runs one time when you open the page, so whatever you echo into your CSS will not change unless you refresh the page. You would need to use JS in order to get an on hover effect

Comment: I based on this article, [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231812/random-background-images-css3[link] but not sure how to use mentioned there JS

Comment: what's your website url?

Comment: https://test3.reksio.net, thank you for support

Comment: The OP in the link specifically says they want a random image on every refresh, not an on hover effect.

Comment: I know but I based on this article, but my goal is to have random image on each box on hover efect, and image will be change when page will be reloaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That css code does not work in css file.
because there is some php code in there.
so if you want to run it, you must use css code in the php/html file.
example.php:

```
<html>
<head>
...
 <style>
 div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1):hover
{
  background: url(images/bg/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

so your index.php page could be like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
  $bg = array('nasa1-400.jpg', 'nasa1-1200.jpg', 'nasa1-640.jpg'); // array of filenames
  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
 <style>
 div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1):hover
{
  background: url(images/bg/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

- This code will show you a new background image whenever you refresh the page.
  If you want to show a new image in every hover without needing to refresh the page, so you have to either use javascript code or javascript + ajax(for fetch new images as live).

**EDITED:**

for that purpose first build a page named rmdimage.php

```
<?php
  $bg = array('nasa1-400.jpg', 'nasa1-1200.jpg', 'nasa1-640.jpg'); // array of filenames
  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
  echo $selectedBg;
```

and you index.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $("div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)").hover(function(){
  $.get("[path-to-php-folder]/rmdimage.php", function(data, status){
  $("div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)").css('background', 'url(images/bg/' + data +') no-repeat;');
    
    //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
 });
</script>
 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="my-element" style="width:100px; height:100px;">this is my fav element!</div>
```

- you must change [path-to-php-folder] to relation rmdimage.php file.
- in the rndimage.php file you can dynamically moderate image array ($bg)

you can fetch them from mysql or a folder , ...

Comment: It is working but I want to applay this rule to each box, and I will do it then same background is display for each so it is not what I want to achive ! I am wondering if there is better approach of my query for example using java script and css instead of php function it will be easier to control my code.

Comment: Do you have any example you to user  javascript code + css or javascript + ajax(for fetch new images as live) ?

Comment: I found another solution but it also not working  :/
in css file
`code`
div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1):hover
{
  background-image: 'randomImage()';
}
`code`
in php
`code`
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Example',
  data() {
    return {
      images: ['images/bg/nasa1-400.jpg', 'images/bg/nasa1-1200.jpg', 'images/bg/nasa1-640.jpg'],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    randomImage() {
      return `url("${
        this.images[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length)]
      }")`;
    },
  },
};
</script>`code`

Comment: I added an example of what you want, in above.

Comment: I implemented but something is wrong and not working, can we get somehow priv?

Comment: you must change [path-to-php-folder] to relation rmdimage.php file.

Comment: rmdimage.php is in smae folder where index.php so I used  $.get("rmdimage.php" or I am wrong?

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: I am not sure you can found out about programming or not.
look at the inspect of browser (inspect panel > network > filter ajax requests) what do you see in sending that request?
it's status code (200 or 404 or 500 or ...) ?
what is response?