# Random Background Images

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core, web-frontend

I wanted to have a random background image each time a page loads, from a list of 5 images.

I was trying to follow this questions,

[Random background images CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231812/random-background-images-css3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but it never gets officially answered, and I can't quite make it work. It feels like it should work though, and I might be missing something simple.

I want to put this in the _Layout page, so it applies to each page. It's kind of TMI, but I'm in VS2019, asp core mvc in c#.

This is what I got:

```
<head>
<style>...</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var totalCount = 8;
        function ChangeIt() {
            var num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * totalCount);
            document.body.background = 'assets/bgImages/' + num + '.jpg';
            document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";    // Background repeat
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>...</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ChangeIt();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access the background property on the body, you're missing the ".style" part and you need to use "url('...')" to set images as background. You can even set image and repeat at the same time.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/pg1u0rn6/

```js
const randomId = 10836835;
const pexelId = '60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597';

document.body.style.background = "url('https://wallpaper.dog/large/" + randomId + ".jpg') repeat";
document.querySelector('.inner').style.background = "url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/" + pexelId + ".jpeg')";
```

```css
body {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner"></div>
```

In you case:

```
document.body.style.background = "url('assets/bgImages/" + num + ".jpg') repeat";
```

Comment: Didn't work. I copy/pasted. any thoughts? I can't even seem to set the background in this way either, like function ChangeIt() {document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/assets/bgImages/2");';}

Comment: @NickFleetwood I updated my answer with code as proof as it's working. I think you might have a problem with the path to you assets. Try adding "./" before the path (like './assets...') of the images. To avoid problems, put the second script at the bottom of the body or, at least, inside the HTML tag, as it's not recommended to put any tag outside the HTML one.

Comment: @NickFleetwood Looking at the code provided yesterday, I know why it wasn't working. I think my editor autocompleted single quotes, so 2 of them shoudn't have been there. The code should be correct now.